# Is it possible to Access all Beacons with ibeacon API?

Tags: ios7, core-location, uuid, ibeacon

i'm close to finish an App using Estimote beacons having their UUID 
hardcoded in my project which list out all the Estimote beacons using ibeacon API, but when i'm trying to make my own device as a beacon transmitter using the Device UUID, which is differ from the estimote UUID, i cannot find it, as the UUID which i mentioned in the code is Estimote's.

So my question is , is there any way that i can find all the beacons(Ex- Estimote Beacons, Kontakt Beacons, Blue cat Beacons and ibeacon hardware) which i can track with apple's ibeacon API?

With same code i wanted to track all beacons without hardcoding any UUID?

is it possible?

Comment: 1) What does this have to do with `xcode`? 2) Please share what you have tried so far such as some form of code.

Comment: @Popeye - there's no need for code, this is a well-known limitation of the iOS API for interacting with iBeacon messages.

Answer (score 1):

No, you *must* tell CoreLocation the ProximityUUID of any iBeacon you want your app to see or it will not tell you about it.  See http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

This does not mean you need to hardcode every UUID in your app. Doing so would require you to resubmit the app for approval each time you add an iBeacon with another UUID.

An alternative is to use a web service to give you a list of UUIDs to search for.  You can build your own, or use my company's [ProximityKit](http://proximitykit.radiusnetworks.com) service that does this for you.

Comment: the certificate for your link is invalid because of a host name mismatch. Is this something you know about or do you have a man in the middle?

Comment: The URL has been changed and the old URL no longer has a cert.  I have corrected the URL.

Answer (score 1):

No,Apple has put restriction on finding of unknown Ibeacon .You can not find any unknown beacon.Though there are some hacks which are not that effective.Also there can not be more than one Udid a app region can contain.What you can do either is that ask the user what Udid he wants to monitor then the app can range for it.
Sorry for wrong spelling if any..

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test bench app for my company that has an array of UUIDs. It saves a default set of UUIDs to user defaults using the registerDefaults call.

The user can then create new UUIDs at will, as well as sharing them with other devices. (I Use a UIActivity, so you can share via AirDrop, messages, email, etc.)

It lets you input a UUID as hex digits, or you can tap a "create new UUID" button to generate a new UUID.

I included the Estimote UUID as well as the 3 UUIDs Apple includes, and a couple of unique ones.

Our test bench app then uses the list of UUIDs for both transmitting and receiving beacon IDs.

So while the UUIDs are stored locally, they are not hard-coded.

You could certainly also fetch a list of UUIDs from a web service as David proposes, or use iCloud to fetch a user-defined list of IDs across all devices that use the same AppleID.

Answer (score 0):

A bitter truth for those who want to discover arbitrary iBeacons and their uuids.

- There doesn't seem to be any hack to look for an arbitrary iBeacon on iOS -- you have to know at least the ProximityUUID to see one.
- Using CoreBluetooth is pretty useless for working with iBeacons. You can see their advertisements, and measure the signal strength, but you can't see any of the identifiers, and thus, you don't even know for sure if any advertisement you see is an iBeacon at all, versus any other BluetoothLE device.

Comment: Yes, but if the poster truly needed to discover unknown UUIDs they could simply use anything *other* than an iDevice.  Since the poster is the manufacturer of the device they wish to detect, they don't really need to discover arbitrary UUIDs, but rather simply have a better infrastructure for configuring the app to discover those applicable at any given time/location.